# Return list of functions with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a data.frame with x,y coordinates and a grouping variable:

```
df<-data.frame(group=c(rep(1,3),rep(2,3),rep(3,3)),
               x=c(rep(c(1,2,3),3)),
               y=c(1,2,3,1,4,9,1,8,27))
```

I would like to have a spline function fitted to each group for later use. Something in the lines of:

```
df %>% group_by(group) %>% .... foo(splinefun(x,y))
```

I do not care for the original data (which contains more than group,x,y), so the return values could be a named list of functions, or anything I can reference with the group variable and get the fitted spline function. Use case is iterating over a second dataset with group and interpolation coordinate x.
Anyone?

#### Edit

So an updated example with newData which contains a group not included in the tibble of fitted functions:

```
df<-data.frame(group=c(rep(1,4),rep(2,4),rep(3,4)),
               x=c(rep(c(0,1,2,3),3)),
               y=c(0,1,2,3,0,1,4,9,0,1,8,27))

fit<-df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarise(fns = list(approxfun(x, y)))

newData <- data.frame(group=c(rep(1,5),rep(2,5),rep(3,5),rep(4,5)) , 
                      xval = rep(c(0,1,2,3,4),4)) %>% 
                      left_join(fit)
```

So the fitted power functions are now joined with the expanded set of groups, where column **fns** is NULL on the missing records. If I can now mutate newData with column **interpolated** applying the functions where **fns** is not NULL and NA otherwise, I would be done.

Comment: If you are iterating over a second dataset, after the summarise step, do a join by 'group' and then do a mutate with the splinefun column applied over the variable of interest in the sceond data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can output the function by wrapping it with `list`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
    group_by(group) %>%
    summarise(fns = list(splinefun(x, y)))
```

If the intention is to create a column in the original data, replace `summarise` with `mutate`.  However, this will repeat the function for each row of the group

---

If we want to apply the functions on another dataset on the corresponding 'group', then do a join with the second dataset and apply the function stored in the first data column on the column of interest in second data using `map2`

```
df %>% 
   group_by(group) %>% 
   summarise(fns = list(splinefun(x, y))) %>% 
   left_join(df2) %>% 
   mutate(newval = map2_dbl(fns, xval, ~ .x(.y)))
```

#### Update

Based on the updated data in the OP's post

```
fit %>% 
  right_join(newData) %>% 
  mutate(newval = map2_dbl(fns, xval, ~ if(!is.null(.x)) .x(.y) else NA_real_))
```

Or create a function with `possibly` (from `purrr`) and apply

```
f1 <- possibly(function(x, y) x(y), otherwise = NA_real_)
fit %>% 
  right_join(newData) %>% 
  mutate(newval = map2_dbl(fns, xval, f1))
```

#### data

```
df2 <- data.frame(group = 1:3, xval = c(1.5, 2.5, 3.2))
newData <- data.frame(group=c(rep(1,5),rep(2,5),rep(3,5),rep(4,5)), 
                   xval = rep(c(0,1,2,3,4),4))
```

Comment: I actually got the same result with "do", but how to i reference the function? Say I want to get y for x=1.5 on group=1 ?

Comment: @user3173412. Do you need `df %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise(val = splinefun(x, y)(1.5))`

Comment: No, i need to apply it to an arbitary number of x`s. I need to iterate over a second data frame with 800 records with groups and x`s.

Comment: Whoh.. That was elegant, the last bit with map2 was a bit over my paygrade. I`m loosing some records in the join, so I would rather keep the set I`m iterating over and have NA`s for the missing ones.(newval). Btw, how would I call a single function directly? I`m feeling a bit stupid, as I have done this in the past: a<-list(x=function(x) x^2) a$x(2)

Comment: @user3173412. May be it is a `right_join`?  Without a reprod example, it is not clear though

Comment: It did indeed :) However, why can I not use the same mutate on my newData<dbl><dbl><list>  where I already left-joined it with fit ?

Comment: @user3173412. I used `newData` as `newData <- data.frame(group=c(rep(1,5),rep(2,5),rep(3,5),rep(4,5)) , 
                      xval = rep(c(0,1,2,3,4),4))`

Comment: @user3173412. Also, the `left_join` will remove the rows where 'group' values are not common

Comment: Yes, but If you run the snip I posted. A bit poluted perhaps having fns in newData, but in any case my newData has group,xval and fns of type dbl,dbl,list. Can not comprehend why yours work, but using the same mutate on my version does not. I.e newData >%>  mutate(newval = map2_dbl(fns, xval, ~ if(!is.null(.x)) .x(.y) else NA_real_))

Comment: @user3173412. Have you loaded plyr along with `dplyr`.  In that case you may need to explicitly use `dplyr::mutate(newval = .`. also can you check `str(newData)` and see if it is a grouped_tbl.  May be `ungroup(newData)` if that is the case

Comment: sure about the join (unless different from SQL, it`s the ow around)? If you run my example you will se that I have all the data I have hardcoded. left_join(x,y), keeps all x`s.. Also you will see I have NULL-entries for the rows not matching, but I still have group and xval in newData. Have not loaded plyr, str(fit) and str(newData) similar.

Comment: Sorry! All is good, it was the ctrl + shift + enter operation that reached a bit further up and grabbed some extra code! DOH! Thanks :) How would I specify this without using the "formula" syntax ?

Comment: @user3173412. Didn't get `formula` part?  Can you please describe

Comment: This  ~ .x(.y) or this part ~ if(!is.null(.x)) .x(.y) else NA_real_). R-specific part (the ~) that bugs me out some times. Is ~.x(.y) equivalent with say inline " function(x,y) x(y) "?

Comment: @user3173412. Yes, it is equivalent to that.  With tilda, the default x, y would be `.x` and `.y` for `map2`

Comment: Thanks! New to verses and tibbles :) This has been enlightening to me, need to read up! Wondering why we can not have a datatype function in our tibble, but need to put it in a list.. I.e a column can have type list, with 1d list entries with function, why not just a column/data type of function...